# Ajax php pdo for each array updating checkbox value to database but facing error on second time

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox, pdo

I was trying to publish but facing problem on second time

when we published initially the values are updating properly in database but when we add new post and trying to to publish all the db values are updated to '0' from '1(prev value)'

```
<button class="btn btn-secondry" id="publish">Publish</button>

$queryNum = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM news where intNewsType= 0 ORDER BY intNewsId");

$postID = $row['intNewsId'];

<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $postID; ?>" /></td>
```

Document Function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#publish").click(function() {
        var data = [];
        $('.checkbox').each(function() {
            data[$(this).attr('value')]=$(this).prop('checked') ? 1: 0;
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "publish.php",
            data: {fields : data},
            success: function() {
                alert('Page published successfully!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

publish.php

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


foreach($_POST['fields'] as $key=>$val)
{
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE news SET intNewsType ='$val'  WHERE intNewsId ='$key'");
    $sql->execute();
}
```

Comment: data[$(this).attr('value')]=$(this).prop('checked')? 1:0;   check this line google proper use

Comment: I changed 
data[$(this).attr('value')]=$(this).prop('checked') ? 1 : 0;

Comment: `SELECT FROM news where intNewsType=0` is that a typo or is actually missing the `*`? `SELECT * FROM ...`. Show us the generated HTML code of the checkboxes. The values are correct? Take a look at the console when you make the POST, which data is being sent?

Comment: intNewsType=o to 1

Answer (score 0):

i don't really understand what you are trying to achieve but this is what i think is wrong with your code.

`$queryNum = $pdo->prepare("SELECT FROM news where intNewsType=0");`
The value you get from the query above `$postID = $row['intNewsId'];` is 1 and when you use it in `<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $postID; ?>" />` it automatically set the value of each checkbox to 1. When you retrieve the values from Jquery, if the previous articles are not checked, it will automatically send 0 instead of 1.